# Change default option on dual boot screen

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I want to know how I can change the default selected option on the GNU GRUB dual boot screen displayed on system start-up.

I have a Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot PC. Currently there is a countdown timer that auto boots into Ubuntu if the time runs out. This is quite annoying since I use Ubuntu seldom.

I do not want to select Windows 7 every time. How can I change the default to Windows 7? See image below of dual boot screen.

[image]